# Решение слау методом Гаусса

Tags: алгоритм

Какой-нибудь алгоритм для решения слау методом Гаусса, без использования классов. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: алгоритм - метод гаусса)) не надо тавтологии) Сам жду ответов, мне как раз эту задачу надо делать)

Comment: А пример с Вики вам не подходит?
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_Гаусса_—_Зейделя

Comment: Ну в гугле примеров просто туча всяких разных, как понятных, так и не особо. .з.

Comment: хах, помню на первом курсе у меня курсач по этой теме был)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое главное это привести систему к треугольному виду.
Первое что приходит в голову это:
Делим все элементы первой сторки на первое число этой строки. 
Получаем строку вида [1 X1 X2 X3 ... XN], где Х - некоторые числа.( первый элемент 1).
Затем умножаем  почленно все элементы первой строки на элемент противоположный первому элементу  нижних строк, и складываем, эти  строки будет выглядеть так  [0 x1 x2 ... xn] (Во всех строках ниже первой строки будет первый элемент 0 ).
Уже вторую строку делим на второй элемент что бы получилась единица, и так далее. 
Старался изложить свою мысль как можно более понятно, надеюсь что у меня это получилось))

Comment: Хочу уточнить ответ: решайте так как вас на вышмате учили.
Также не забудьте, от вас скорее всего будут ждать не того как вы на бумажке решаете, а без сортировки для удобства строк.

Если вам интересны СЛАУ, я бы рекомендовал сделать оба варианта. Более оптимизированный метод в любом случае будет более ценен чем обычный лобовой.